# Как, используя vk api, получить информацию о записи на стене зная id записи?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне необходимо, зная id записи (не важно где, на стене, в сообществе и т.д.), получить информацию о ней (owner_id, text, date и т.п.), используя Vk API. Я находил только как получить информацию о записи со стены, из сообщества и т.д., но мне нужно получить информацию о любой (доступной) записи зная только её id. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ. Это делается через метод wall.getById, в параметр posts необходимо передать данные такого вида: пользователь_запись, где пользователь - id автора(пользователь, сообщество и т.д.), запись - id записи. Документация - https://vk.com/dev/wall.getById